# Сортировка массива по определённому ключу

Tags: php

```
$arr = array(
    "Человек1"=>array("Вохминцев","Сергей",170, 80, 450 ), 
    "Человек2"=>array("Гульдяев","Артём",160,65,470), 
    "Человек3"=>array("Зимин","Никита", 165,60,350),
    "Человек4"=>array("Махнёв","Филипп",178,68, 500), 
    "Человек5"=>array("Морозов","Виталий",182,75,520),
    "Человек6"=>array("Пестов","Юрий",  180,80,485 ), 
    "Человек7"=>array("Соснин", "Сергей",160,61,510), 
    "Человек8"=>array("Столбин","Сергей",192,80,490),
    "Человек9"=>array("Токарев","Юрий", 157,50,480 ), 
    "Человек10"=>array("Третьяков","Владимир",170,85,460 ),
    "Человек11"=>array("Филиппов","Дмитрий",181,75,300 )
);
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    asort($value[4]);
    echo $value[4];
}
```

Нужно отсортировать по 4 ключу и вывести эти значения, т.е 300, 350, 450 и т.д.

Вроде, можно сделать через usort, но я, к сожалению, не понимаю как применить эту функцию в данном массиве.

И ещё вопрос, какой функцией можно воспользоваться, чтобы этот массив разбить на 4 по 4/3 человека?

Comment: добавьте больше описания, не особо понятно что вы хотите получить в результате

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
usort($arr, function($a, $b) { 
    return $a[4] <=> $b[4]; 
});

// или в 7.4
usort($arr, fn($a, $b) => $a[4] <=> $b[4]);
```

---

А для разбиения на части можно использовать **[array_chunk](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-chunk.php)**, т.е. будет:

```
$chunckedArray = array_chunk($arr, 4);
```

---

Вывод Фамилия+Имя разбитые по 4.

```
usort($arr, fn($a, $b) => $a[4] <=> $b[4]);
$usersFio = array_map(fn($item) => "{$item[0]} $item[1]", $arr);
$chunckedUsersFio = array_chunk($usersFio, 4);

print_r($chunckedUsersFio);
```

Comment: Массив разбивается, но как можно вывести только имена? Т.е. должны выводиться "Сергей, Артём, Никита, Филипп" и с новой строки следующие 4

Comment: @Kirai двойной цикл. Посмотрите что внутри `$chunckedArray` и поймёте

Comment: @Kirai даже лучше сделать вначале сортировку, потом получение ФИО (или что там надо) и потом разбитие на части. Добавил в ответ. А как по разбитым данным проходится циклом - это уже вы должны знать. Это основы

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array(
    "Человек1"=>array("Вохминцев","Сергей",170, 80, 450 ), 
    "Человек2"=>array("Гульдяев","Артём",160,65,470), 
    "Человек3"=>array("Зимин","Никита", 165,60,350),
    "Человек4"=>array("Махнёв","Филипп",178,68, 500), 
    "Человек5"=>array("Морозов","Виталий",182,75,520),
    "Человек6"=>array("Пестов","Юрий",  180,80,485 ), 
    "Человек7"=>array("Соснин", "Сергей",160,61,510), 
    "Человек8"=>array("Столбин","Сергей",192,80,490),
    "Человек9"=>array("Токарев","Юрий", 157,50,480 ), 
    "Человек10"=>array("Третьяков","Владимир",170,85,460 ),
    "Человек11"=>array("Филиппов","Дмитрий",181,75,300 )
);
usort($arr, function($a, $b) { return $a[4] > $b[4] ? 1 : -1; });
print_r($arr);
```